# Get array's index as result of smartmatch operation?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to obtain the index of the match resulted from a comparison between a scalar and an array done with the smartmatch operator (`~~`)?

```
if ( $str ~~ @data ) {
   #code to get index of array where match occurred
}
```

The expression in the conditional will return true if there is a match, so that isn't of any help.

I do like the smartmatch operator in very simple cases; I don't use it on any wild comparisons like data structure vs data structure or some other madness.

Comment: ***Don't use smartmatch***. The [perldelta for version 18.0](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental) says that ***The smartmatch family of features are now experimental***: *"Relying on its current behaviour is not recommended."*

Comment: @Borodin: if one should never use experimental features, there would be no point in ever having them.  better to say, before using it you should be aware...

Comment: @ysth: Experimental features should be used for *experimentation*. I think it is fair to assume that questions posted on SO are about *production* software unless the poster clearly says otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a way in the docs (`perldoc perlop`).

[List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);

my @data = qw(red white blue green);
my $i = firstidx { $_ eq 'blue' } @data;
print "$i\n";

__END__

2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a decorator. Depending on the context this could be programmed more compactly, but this is the general idea:

```
my $i = 0;
my @matches =
    map  { $_->[0] }
    grep { $_->[1] eq $str }
    map  { [ $i++, $_ ] } @data;

if (@matches) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: The “*decorate-sort-undecorate*” pattern is called a “*Schwartzian Transform*” in Perl parlance. In a sorting algorithm, caching the sort index instead of recalculating it for each comparison can get cheaper. But here, you are just doing a simple `grep` and save nothing (not even array accesses). Instead: `my @matches = grep { $data[$_] eq $str } 0 .. $#data`.

Comment: @amon This occurred to me directly after submitting it, but the OP had already solved his issue. Thank you though.